# Big margin bottom in compound control

Tags: android

I made a compound control, but when i add this new component into a XML layer with other standard components(e.g. TextView), when this layer is inflated, the compound control has a big margin added in the bottom separating this from the others components. I tried adding Layer_bottomMargin = 0dp without success, the only way to resolve this, is adding layer_height a fixed value (i.e. 15dp) instead "wrap_content", but this solution is not fine for me, due i want remove dinamically some component from my compound control.

The code of my compound control:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left|top"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fieldset_margin"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_default"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/fieldset_lines_shadow"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/fieldset_lines_light"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the code of my layer including this compound control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#C8D5F6FF"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    >
    <com.apps.example.Header
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/fieldset_text_secondary"
        android:text="nananananan"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fieldset_margin"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Sorry but this is my first post and i can't upload images.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved partially by overwriting the onMeasure method in my compound control class. I did not this before because in the official documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

says that is not necessary overwrite this method when is creating a compound control.

Anyway, this is partial solution due when an individual control of the compound is programmatically turned invisible (GONE) occurs the same issue mentioned in the original post but with smaller margin space.

I will continue trying to resolve this, but for now, this is my solution.

Thanks!